# Sending a click event to two completely overlapping layers (with child nodes)

Tags: javascript, dispatchevent

Ok, I have page (html, javascript, css) with two layers that completely cover the browser window. The one in front contains a navigation that should clickable. The one in the back contains a map with markers that should also be clickable. The navigation (the one in the front) at times can occupy the complete window height and width so limiting it's size is not really an option.

Now the problem is how to get the click events to the back layer so the map markers can receive their click event. backlayer.dispatchEvent(e) takes backlayer as the event target, but any of my markers inside the backlayer could be the target, so I was wondering if there is a simpler way then check the bounding-box of every map marker element and call dispatchEvent on the map marker that matches directly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you given them explicit z-indexes?

Comment: No, and would prefer not to do so either

Comment: It just strikes me as the most straightforward solution to assign their display/click priorities as z-indexes (indices?).  Or am I misreading the problem?

Comment: I think you are misreading.The front and back layer both have child elements. The child elements of both layers can occur more or less anywhere inside the parent layer (the whole window) and are visible at all times (the front layer is transparent except for it's child elements). The child elements of both layers should be able to receive click events. Does this clear up things?

Comment: That was my understanding, and it's similar to a problem I've had recently.  If you take the back layer's child element and give it a z-index higher than that of the front layer, it will get its display/block/positioning properties from its parent, but be directly clickable.

Comment: Hmm, I forgot to mention that child elements in the front layer con overlap child elements in the bottom layer but the child elements in the front layer should always be visible on top of the ones in the back layer in case of overlapping. Sorry for the fragmented explanation.

Comment: In that case the front layer's child elements can be given a higher z-index than the back layer's children.  You have the two layers which constrain their respective child elements on the page, with the children floating on top with their own priorities.  Unless the layers themselves need to be clickable, you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. The thing is I simplified my situation a bit because I thought the details didn't matter, but using this solution I would complicate my code more than calculating bounding boxes and calling dispatchEvent I think. The combination of back and front layers occur more than once on the screen, and they need to be neatly separated, so I would need to calculate the z-index in code. Your solution works, but I failed to explain my real constraints, sorry for that (first question). I'll go ahead with bounding boxes, which I just got working. Not really clean but hey. Thank you!

Comment: No worries.  Sorry I didn't have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jQuery or a similar library to simulate a click on the bottom layer when clicking the upper one.